# Compiler Friendly Tail Recursion + Tail Recursion Checking in ATS

Tags: tail-call-optimization, ats

What is the best way to check that a function has been tail call optimized in ATS? (So far I have been running "top" to see if memory usage is constant)

As a follow up: Say you have a complex tail-recursive function that the compiler has failed to TCO, is there a way to re-write it in a more compiler friendly way? Or in such a way to force the compiler to attempt TCO?

Comment: In the [ATS Book](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/DOCUMENT/INT2PROGINATS/HTML/x620.html) it is implied that it should be done automatically The wiki implies that [fun](https://github.com/githwxi/ATS-Postiats/wiki/keywords) can be TCO'd, but no mention of how to make certain it is. I agree this would be nice to have if it isn't there, e.g., Scala has `@tailrec`.  No mention is made of `fnx` on the wiki, but based on grepping comments, I think this is something to do with templates. Worst case scenario: I imagine you could inspect the C output code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a peculiar way to do it in ATS2.

Say you have

```
fnx foo(...) = bar(...)
and bar(...) = ...bar...
```

If the body of bar contains a non-tail-recursive call to bar, then
the C compiler is to complain with an error message.

Things become a lot more challenging when (linear) streams are involved. A seemingly non-tail-recursive function can run without concern of stack overflow because it essentially saves its stack on heap (and then frees it): This is a place where ATS really shines!

Comment: What is the difference between `fnx` and `fun`, especially in this regard? Do you have an example for the latter instance using linear streams? Sounds interesting. Reminds me of hole punching, but different.

Comment: `fnx` is used to define mutually tail-recursive functions.

Comment: What I said is not related to hole punching. Please read the chapter on lazy stream-processing in the book of the title *Crash into FP via ATS*.